# How can I get the taxonomy tree by the vocabulary ID?

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms

I want load all the taxonomy terms by their vocabulary ID in Drupal 8. In Drupal 7, I would use the following code.

```
$terms = taxonomy_get_tree($vid);
```

What code should I use in Drupal 8?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code snippet might help you.

```
$terms = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->loadTree($vid,0,NULL,TRUE);
print_r($terms);
```

Answer (score 9):

You can load terms using the entity query,

```
$terms =\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->loadTree($vid);
foreach ($terms as $term) {
     $term_data[] = array(
      "id" => $term->tid,
      "name" => $term->name
     );
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.I used that and when I dpm($terms) result show like this.

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [__CLASS__] => stdClass
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [__CLASS__] => stdClass
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [__CLASS__] => stdClass
        )

)

Comment: You can loop through the array to get term id and name. Updated the answer.